# RRDTool functions returns void value since PHP 5.4 upgrade

Tags: php, debugging, debian, php-5.4, rrdtool

We have a php application that makes a heavy use of RRDTool both in Web scripts and CLI scripts.

Since we upgraded to `debian wheezy` on which `php 5.4` is the default, our `rrdtool` functions return just void at each call, with absolutely no error. 
These function seem to be really called, as changing the name to a fake one rises an error, but the result is empty (even for `rrd_version()`)

PHP 5.4 is compiled with rrd support, `rrdtool` and `librrd4` are installed. The commmand line ̀ rrdtool`works well. We tried to install`php5-rrdtool`, we tried the same stack on another machine which worked well and we can't find any similar experience on internet.

`strace` shows no external call to rrd files (so it doesn't even start to read the file we provide), `LD_DEBUG=all` shows plenty of symbols from `librrd4` (so the library seems to be really linked)

We do think it's a problem bound to our very system, a conflict or something like that, but we can't figure out how to debug it. Do you have some idea on how to debug this painful problem [ah, and I forgot to say it's a production-only problem, with thousands of graphs not served since yesterday to our clients :-(]

Comment: I don't know rrdtool, so I probably can't give an actual answer for you, but you say "*it's a production-only problem*" ... does that mean you did the 5.4 upgrade on your dev systems and it worked? If so, that would imply that PHP 5.4 itself isn't the issue, maybe something else related to the upgrade. Have you checked your PHP.ini for anything that might be different?

Comment: You're right, it works on another machine with the exact same configuration